# How to get any enum value which is not a given enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I would like to get any value of the existing in a given enum which is not n.
I'll try to explain it better given I have an enum

```
public enum EFileFormat
{
    Rtf,
    Word,
    Pdf,
    Html,
    Txt
}
```

And a variable with the any value of the enum for example

```
EFileFormat.Word
```

I would like to get any value of the enum which is not "EFileFormat.Word". I have come to this code but i think a more elegant way must exist:

```
var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(EFileFormat), format);
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(EFileFormat)).Where(n => !n.Equals(name));
var otherFormat = (EFileFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(EFileFormat), names.First());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(EFileFormat), **format**); what is format?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Would you like to list all other values of the enum or just get a random one that is not the one you have?

Comment: `Enum.GetNames(typeof(EFileFormat)).Any(n => !n.Equals(name));`

Comment: Why don't you add another enum value with the name `Invalid` or `None`?

Comment: @DanielTshuva: From context, I assume `var format = EFileFormat.Word;` the "exclusion" value OP is talking about.

Comment: Trying to do this based on names seems like a bad idea if this is meant to be "generic" to any enum - some enums have multiple names for the same underlying numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning flag values to the Enum will allow you to do this - if you can change the Enum values.

> See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types#enumeration-types-as-bit-flags

```
[Flags]
public enum EFileFormat
{
    Rtf = 0x1,
    Word = 0x2,
    Pdf = 0x4,
    Html = 0x8,
    Txt = 0x16
}

...

// this will be equal to only word
var word = EFileFormat.Word;

// this will be equal to every value except word    
var notWord = ~EFileFormat.Word;

// this will be equal to Html and Pdf
var value = EFileFormat.Html | EFileFormat.Pdf;

// this will be equal to Html
var html = value - EFileFormat.Pdf;

// this will check if a value has word in it
if(notWord == (notWord & EFileFormat.Word))
{
   // it will never reach here because notWord does not contain word,
   // it contains everything but word.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mupltiple conversion enumValue <-> enumName use `GetValues` method.

Linq `First()` method has an overload with a predicate, use it to avoid `Where()`

```
var format = EFileFormat.Word;      
var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EFileFormat))
    .OfType<EFileFormat>()
    .First(x => x != format);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach from values instead of names like this;

```
var someOtherFormat =(EFileFormat)Enum.GetValues(typeof(EFileFormat).First(i=>i =! (int)EFileFormat.Word);
```

Comment: `.Where(i=>i =! (int)EFileFormat.Word).First()` can just be written as `.First(i=>i =! (int)EFileFormat.Word)`

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Edited as your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EFileFormat))
                .OfType<EFileFormat>()
                .Where(x => !x.Equals(EFileFormat.Word)).ToList();
```

Comment: will this be more feasible

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: yes @Eel Lee i am new to SO, sorry will try to learn the habit of explaining my answers